# Negative Lookahead Mistake

Tags: regex

I want to get these strings

```
84fyctvvtvxy.jpg
84fyctv_vtv(test)-_xy.jpg
```

but not these strings

```
84fyctvvtvxy_t.jpg
84fyctvvtv(test)-_xy_t.jpg
```

I tried this RegEx

```
([A-Za-z0-9 ()€_]+(?!(.|.)_t))\.jpg
```

I need to exclude string that ends with `_t.jpg`

But it doesn't work can anyone help please?

Comment: What language/tool? What are you trying to match with `(.|.)`?

Comment: Is it C#? JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?!.*_t\.jpg$)[\w()€ .-]+$
```

- `^` Assert beginning of line.
- `(?!.*_t\.jpg$)` Negative lookahead, checks that substring is not at end of string.
- `[\w()-.]+` Match any character in the character set.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/P5XsrR/2).

Comment: This one don't work, second one from das linke light works. Why this doesn't?

Comment: Where are you testing this regex? If a negative lookbehind works, a negative lookahead should also work.

Comment: @quinique [Is this what you are using?](https://learn.co/lessons/regex-lab)

Comment: I tried on mobile RegEx Lab App, online both work! Thank you! Resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using a negative *lookbehind* `(?<!_t)` for the `\.jpg` part of the pattern, like this:

```
([A-Za-z0-9 ()€_-]+)(?<!_t)\.jpg
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/HueUK1/1)